# Selecting vertex on z axis using python

Tags: python

I've been searching high and low for a python script to select the highest or lowest vertex or vertices on the z axis in an object. I want to add these to a vertex group so I can use them in my code.
Any help is appreciated.. thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import bpy

# get the object and its vertices
obj = bpy.context.object # edit: now gets the currently active object 

# edit: to select vertices we have to be in OBJ mode first:
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")

verts = obj.data.vertices
# get the z-coordinates from each vertex and the maximum
z_coords = [v.co[2] for v in verts]
max_z_coord = max(z_coords)

# get list of all vertices that have the max. z-coordinate
max_verts = [vertex for vertex in obj.data.vertices if vertex.co[2] == max_z_coord]
```

Edit:

To *select* vertices, one way is to change to OBJECT mode, 
select the vertices, and change back to EDIT mode. (Another one would be to use `bmesh`.)

Notice that I've also changed two lines in the original answer above: We have to work on the active object (`obj = bpy.context.object`) and we have to be in OBJECT mode (`bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="OBJECT")`).

The selection and switching to EDIT mode is done by appending these lines to the script:

```
# select the vertices: 
for v in verts: v.select = False
for v in max_verts: v.select = True
# set EDIT mode's select mode to "vertex select" 
bpy.context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode = (True , False , False)
# change to EDIT mode
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT")
```

Comment: I've tried, but nothing seems to happen. The cone, when I enter edit mode, does not select the top vertex. I'm using 2.8

Comment: I've edited my answer to _select_ the vertices in edit mode as well. Let me know if it still doesn't work or if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 2):

**Edit BMesh version**

An edit mode script to select the maximum z value vertices.

Uses local space, edit to `space = 'GLOBAL'` for global space.

Uses a tolerance of `TOL = 0.0000001` to check between values. Edit to suit. Set to zero for no tolerance

Sorted the vertices in z order.  This is less efficient than finding the max.  If though you also want the min the median, the top 10 etc, will come down to simple list slicing.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Matrix

space = 'LOCAL'  # or 'GLOBAL'
find = 'MAX' # or 'MIN'
TOL = 1e-7
ob = bpy.context.object
M = ob.matrix_world if space == 'GLOBAL' else Matrix()
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
verts = sorted(bm.verts, key=lambda v: (M @ v.co).z)

bm.select_flush(False)
#bm.select_flush_mode()
z = (M @ verts[-1 if find == 'MAX' else 0].co).z
for v in verts:
    v.select = abs((M @ v.co).z - z) < TOL
bm.select_flush(True)    


bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

For example to add the top 3 verts to a vertex group `vg` named "Group"  Would need to do this in object mode

```
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
verts = sorted(bm.verts, key=lambda v: (M @ v.co).z)
vg = ob.vertex_groups.new(name="Top 3")
vg.add([v.index for v in verts[:3], 1.0, 'REPLACE')
vg = ob.vertex_groups.new(name="Lowest 3")
vg.add([v.index for v in verts[-3:], 1.0, 'REPLACE')
```

Comment: Would this work for 2.79 as well?

Comment: Yes. Need to replace @ (at) with * (asterisk)  [Assumed 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139172/selecting-vertex-on-z-axis-using-python/139291?noredirect=1#comment238050_139200)

Comment: In order to get the Y vertices, would you replace the "z" with "y"?

Comment: Yes that would work.